# Cypress: How to access the body of a POST-request?

Tags: integration-testing, cypress

**Is there a way in Cypress to check the body of a POST-request?**

E.g.: I have entered some data in a form, then pressed "Submit". 
The form-data is send via POST-request, separated by a blank line from the header-data.

I would like to check the form-data. If all data, which I have entered, are included and if they are correct.

Is that possible with Cypress?

```
cy.get('@login').then(function (xhr) {
    const body = xhr.requestBody;
    console.log(xhr);
    expect(xhr.method).to.eq('POST');
});
```

The xhr-object doesn't have the transferred data included.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should be possible.

```js
describe('Capturing data sent by the form via POST method', () => {
  before(() => {
    Cypress.config('baseUrl', 'https://www.reddit.com');
    cy.server();
    cy.route({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/login'
    }).as('redditLogin');
  });
  it('should capture the login and password', () => {
    cy.visit('/login');
    cy.get('#loginUsername').type('username');
    cy.get('#loginPassword').type('password');
    cy.get('button[type="submit"]').click();

    cy.wait('@redditLogin').then(xhr => {
      cy.log(xhr.responseBody);
      cy.log(xhr.requestBody);
      expect(xhr.method).to.eq('POST');
    })
  });
});
```

This is how you can inspect your data in Chrome Developer Tool.

[image: This is how you can inspect your data in Chrome Developer Tool]

You should see the same thing you've seen from Chrome Developer Tool when you run your test in Cypress.

[image: You should see the same thing you've seen from Chrome Developer Tool when you run your test in Cypress]

Comment: How would you verify the status?

Answer (score 3):

I was Googling the same problem and somehow landed here before reaching the documentation.

Anyway, have you tried something like:

```
cy.wait('@login').should((xhr) => {
  const body = xhr.request.body

  expect(body).to.match(/email/)
})
```

I haven't tested it out with a `multipart/form-data` encoded request, but I suspect that you'll also find the request body that way.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use **cy.intercept()** in order to spy, stub and assert network requests and responses.

```
// assert that a request to this route
// was made with a body that included 'user'
cy.wait('@someRoute').its('request.body').should('include', 'user')

// assert that a request to this route
// received a response with HTTP status 500
cy.wait('@someRoute').its('response.statusCode').should('eq', 500)

// assert that a request to this route
// received a response body that includes 'id'
cy.wait('@someRoute').its('response.body').should('include', 'id')
```

Link to the [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Using-the-yielded-object)